# ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError when joining tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting a somewhat cryptic error message of

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError 1

when trying to execute `@invoices = invoice.joins(pos: [vendor_id: 1])`

I am trying to call all invoices that belong to POs that belong to Vendor 1.

My models are setup as follows:
Vendors can have many POs, and POs can have many invoices

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :pos

class Po < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :vendor
  has_many :items, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :invoices

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :po
```

I gather that the ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError is

> Raised when association is being configured improperly or user tries
>   to use offset and limit together with ActiveRecord::Base.has_many or
>   ActiveRecord::Base.has_and_belongs_to_many associations.

But I'm having trouble figuring out what's wrong with my associations. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your associations are OK... I think your statement is just bad, and usually when I need to query like this, I resort to a little SQL clause because it's either too complex or flat-out hard to read otherwise.

Try this (note the capital I in Invoice):

```
vendor_id = 1
@invoices = Invoice.joins(:po).where("pos.vendor_id = ?", vendor_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That more or less worked, albeit with a minor syntax tweak: 
@invoices = Invoice.joins(:po).where("pos.vendor_id = ?", vendor_id)

Comment: Cool... glad it helped. Would you mark the answer as correct please?